# Need help to pass multiple values to single parameters in case?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I am new to dynamic query and I am stuck in a situation which is that I have to pass multiple values to a single parameter of a stored procedure. But the thing is there can a filter or there may be not.

Meaning there can be a where clause for that paramtere or the may be not.

I can have conditions in where clause which can be null sometimes or those conditions would have some values.

I am stuck when the paramter have multiple values and these have to be passed in where clause.

I have written a small code and I am able to get if the value in filter is 0 i.e. there is no filter for that particular column and for passing a single parameter but I don't how to pass multiple parameter. I looked for it there are wy through XML which I can't use and also UDF which my senior dont want to add more load. So, is there way to pass multiple parameter without using any temp table or UDF?

I am posting my code here:

```
alter procedure db.test_1
    (@param1 varchar(10), @param2 varchar(10),
     @param3 varchar(10), @param4 varchar(10), @param5 varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare @id varchar(250)
    declare @type varchar(250) 
    declare @xyz varchar(250)
    declare @name varchar(250)
    declare @abc varchar(250)
    declare @sql varchar(800)

    set @id = case when convert(varchar,@param1)='0' then ''
                      when @param1 like '%%' then 'id in ('+convert(varchar,@param)+')'
                      else 'id='+@param1 end ;
    set @type = case when convert(varchar,@param2)='0' then ''
                      else '@type='+@param2 end ;

    set @xyz = case when convert(varchar,@param3)='0' then ''
                      else '@xyz='+@param3 end ;

    set @name = case when convert(varchar,@param4)='0' then ''
                      else '@name='+@param4 end ;

    set @abc = case when convert(varchar,@param5)='0' then ''
                      else '@abc='+@param5 end ;

    set @sql = 'select sum(column_1) from db.test_1 where '+@id+'and'+@type+'and'+@xyz+'and'+@name+'and'+ @abc

    select @sql; -- to know what query is running
    --execute(@sql)
end
```

And I need help here:

```
case when convert(varchar,@param1)='0' then ''
                      when @param1 like '%%' then 'carrier_id in ('+convert(varchar,@param)+')'
                      else 'id='+@param1 end ;
```

Here how do I tell that `'%%'` meaning is there are mltiple paramter are passing

Please your any help is welcomed and if you don't understand anything please just comment?

Comment: `LIKE '%%'` meaning all paramter *NOT NULL* can passing

Comment: It means that multiplr values can pass through a single paramter 
like 
execute db.test_1 '23,26,27','23' etc...
This is where I face problem as how to I tell compiler that we are passing multiple values.yeah not null only

Comment: Why convert everywhere? @paramX are varchar. you don't need to convert them to varchar. And if you do, add the correct length and don't use varchar alone, use varchar(X).

Comment: yeah you are correct I dont need convert thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
alter  procedure test_1
    (@param1 varchar(10), @param2 varchar(10),
     @param3 varchar(10), @param4 varchar(10), @param5 varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare @id varchar(250)
    declare @type varchar(250) 
    declare @xyz varchar(250)
    declare @name varchar(250)
    declare @abc varchar(250)
    declare @sql varchar(800)

    set @id = case when convert(varchar,@param1)='0' then '1=1'
                      when @param1 like '%%' then 'id in ('+convert(varchar,@param1)+')' end ;
    set @type = case when convert(varchar,@param2)='0' then '1=1'
                      else '@type='+@param2 end ;

    set @xyz = case when convert(varchar,@param3)='0' then '1=1'
                      else '@xyz='+@param3 end ;

    set @name = case when convert(varchar,@param4)='0' then '1=1'
                      else '@name='+@param4 end ;

    set @abc = case when convert(varchar,@param5)='0' then '1=1'
                      else '@abc='+@param5 end ;

    set @sql = 'select sum(column_1) from db.test_1 where '+@id+' and '+@type+' and '+@xyz+' and '+@name+' and '+ @abc

    select @sql; -- to know what query is running  --execute(@sql)
end
```

call for this sp as

```
execute test_1 @param1 = '12,12', @param2 = '0',
     @param3 = '0', @param4 = '0', @param5 = '0'
```

the "In" keyword work for both "ID =" and "ID in"